# How can I replicate random draws in RcppArmadillo?

Tags: r, rcpp

Here's a C++ function to draw `N` independent normal deviates with mean zero and standard deviation `s`

```
// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]

#include <RcppArmadillo.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]] 
List rnorm_cpp(double s, int N){

    arma::colvec epsilon = s * arma::randn(N);
    return List::create(Named("e") = epsilon);

}
```

And here's a (virtually identical) R version

```
rnormR <- function(s, N){

  epsilon <- rnorm(N, mean = 0, sd = s)
  return(list(e = epsilon))

}
```

After sourcing `rnorm_cpp` and `rnormR` I ran the following:

```
set.seed(1234)
fooR <- rnormR(s = 5, N = 10)

set.seed(1234)
barR <- rnormR(s = 5, N = 10)

set.seed(1234)
fooCpp <- rnorm_cpp(s = 5, N = 10)

set.seed(1234)
barCpp <- rnorm_cpp(s = 5, N = 10)
```

Finally, I ran `identical` and got the following results:

```
> identical(fooR, barR)
[1] TRUE
> identical(barR, fooCpp)
[1] FALSE
> identical(fooCpp, barCpp)
[1] FALSE
```

I was expecting to get `TRUE` for all three of these. How can I: (1) replicate random draws across calls to `rnorm_cpp` and (2) get identical draws for calls to `rnormR` and `rnorm_cpp`?

Comment: Wouldn't you need to assume that the RNG for Rcpp was the same as for R? A dubious proposition.

Comment: Because it is true :)   That has been an Rcpp feature all along -- but here he is calling _Armadillo's_ RNG, and that assumption is indeed dubious as I just detailed.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The function `arma::randn()` is **not** connected to the R RNGs, so calling `set.seed()` has
no influence on it.

What we do in Rcpp is to take advantage of the fine R API which permits us to access the *same* RNGs from R and C++.  And by being careful with `RNGScope` instances (which get inserted automagically) the RNG state is always correct between R and C++.

But you simply cannot assume that any other third-party RNG (here: Arma's) was automatically aligned as well. Moreover, in this particular case, Conrad's documentation for Armadillo is clear:

> To change the seed, use the `std::srand()` function

To clarify (Hi, @DWin) here is full R and C++ example:

```
R> set.seed(42); rnorm(5)           ## Five N(0,1) draws in R
[1]  1.3710 -0.5647  0.3631  0.6329  0.4043
R> cppFunction('NumericVector foo(int n) { return rnorm(n); }')
R> set.seed(42); foo(5)             ## Five N(0,1) draws from C++ fun.
[1]  1.3710 -0.5647  0.3631  0.6329  0.4043
R>
```

We get the same numbers via R and C++ as we a) seed the RNGs identically and b) do in fact call the same RNG provided by R.

Comment: Right: that makes sense. So if I implement the first example from here: http://gallery.rcpp.org/articles/timing-normal-rngs/ I'll be able to set the seed as expected?

Comment: Use the Rcpp variant of `rnorm()`, then assign to arma vector.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel, what I've understood from your answer here is that there is no way to find a mapping between seed numbers in Arma and R? If you wanted to validate a function you've written in Arma with a function in R, what would you do then? Thanks very much.

Comment: That is a statistical problem with a statistical answer. You have two different generators, and you need to make distributional comparisons of your outcomes. Or else you avoid the issue and use the R RNG in your C++ code.  Which is Rcpp's default.